# declaring a variable globally so that can be reused anywhere in c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, petapoco

I went through many links but couldn't find my answer.Links such as [Global variables for setting configurations ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890776/global-variables-for-setting-configurations-asp-net-mvc?answertab=votes#tab-top) , [ASP.NET MVC C# global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365705/asp-net-mvc-c-sharp-global-variable?rq=1), [ASP.NET MVC Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118610/asp-net-mvc-global-variables/5119154#5119154) and many more all of them suggest some complex methods like using Application_Start or using session variables, singleton pattern. But I don't want to use these, I just want declare a variable in a certain file and access it anywhere I need.

```
var dataContext = new PetaPoco.Database("MessageEntity");
```

This line is required anywhere I need to access the database. So I want to declare this dataContext as global variable in a certain different file and access it on my several other controllers. How would I accomplish this. Please help!!

Comment: I think this answer could help u 

Salut!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118610/asp-net-mvc-global-variables

Comment: The link in the previous comment is your answer. But beware, your creating a [God class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), this is the start of a maintenance nightmare. Change your design while you still can! Use dependency injection instead.

Comment: Ok If Its such a bad programming practice, I may not use it. But want to know how it is done. I wrote a separate class public static class DatabaseEntity
    {
        
        public DatabaseEntity()
        { 
        var dataContext = new PetaPoco.Database("MessageEntity");
        }
    } Now how will I use this class elsewhere

Comment: Why is this needing to be done? What are you trying to achieve by having a variable globally set?? Also, you should try the configuration file, `web.config`

Comment: I recommend learning about dependency injection and IoC-Containers.

Comment: I just want to declare the database entity at one place and use it every where else for that do I need dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

to create global variable:

```
public static class Global
{
    public volatile static Object GlobalVariable;
}
```

It can be accessed everywhere from apllication thru Global.GlobalVariable.

but it is bad solution for data access context.